# PHP EWS - Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unauthorized in

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, php-ews

I am using https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews library to connect to our Microsft Exchange Server 2010 SP3 but I am getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unauthorized in

[image: see error message here]

I am using the example provided under: /examples/message/create.php

and the error is triggered on this line:
index.php

```
$response = $client->CreateItem($request);
```

Client.php

```
$response = $this->soap->{$operation}($request);
```

When I try to access the wsdl file from the browser it works fine and after authentication, I can see all the options under Services.wsdl .

What do you think the problem is?
Is there some settings that I need to enable on Microsoft Exchange in order to use the SOAP services?

Comment: the error is fairly self-explanatory.  Your PHP script hasn't done whatever it needs to do to authenticate itself for access to the features of the SOAP server.  As I don't know what you're expected to do to authenticate against the particular SOAP server in question I don't think there's much else anybody can do to help you other than to find out what the authentication requirements are.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes, it could also be that PHP script hasn't done all it needs to finalize the authentication but as mentioned, I am using the PHP-EWS library and I wonder how others managed to make it work.